# Why UV light causes sunburn if exposed for too long, whereas visible light does not?

Tags: thermal-radiation

UV light causes sunburn if exposed for too long, whereas visible light does not. Why?

Comment: ... it's called sunburn for a reason.  This question doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Sunlight does, but $E = h\nu$ is probably the answer you are looking for.

Comment: this question come up in the last year final examination of modern physics

Comment: @HRainsworth I doubt if it was worded that way.  As is it doesn't make sense.  _Sunburn_ is specifically a UV burn from the sun.

Comment: I just copy and paste that question exactly

Comment: If that's actually how the question was worded then it's wrong, because you can really, definitely, get sunburn from sunlight.

Comment: I've made what seems to be the obvious clarifying edit. HRainsworth, if you don't like my change please feel free to roll it back.

Comment: @HRainsworth If that was the _exact_ question, the answer is basically "this question is bad".  John's edit seems to be what was intended (but I can't say for sure).

Comment: it doesn't matter, I just hope this question doesn't come up again this Thursday. Thanks

Comment: @HRainsworth If they ask about these topics it's probably best you do actually understand what is asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand this effect, we have to think of light as a stream of photons.  Each photon has a particular wavelength, and shorter wavelength photons (such as those of UV) have a higher energy than those of longer wavelength photons (such as those of visible light).

Many chemical processes require what is called an "activation energy" to happen.  You can think of it like a hill between your starting point and your destination.  You need enough energy to get up the hill before you can roll down to your destination.  If you don't have enough energy, you end up rolling part way up the hill, and then rolling back down.

Sunburn is associated with damage caused by these chemical processes.  When a UV photon hits some compounds in the body (such as DNA), it has enough energy to "break" it, causing a chemical reaction that results in changes that have to be repaired by the body later.  Visible light photons lack the energy to get past this barrier, so they can't cause the same damage.

The reason UV and visible light are so different is that UV light is called "ionizing radiation."  It has enough energy to actually kick electrons off of atoms.  Visible light is "non-ionizing radiation," and generally doesn't have the energy to do this -- if it tries to kick an electron off of the atom, the atom has enough "pull" to hold onto it.  The ability to knock electrons off of atoms is a pretty powerful tool for causing chemical reactions to occur, so the division between ionizing and non-ionizing is a pretty big deal.